# Rails + js.erb + form inside form + ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I need to have a form within a form. Basically, I have a main form, inside the main form is a button and when clicked , a slidedown appears with two text fields, which takes username and password. Once clicked submit, I want it to call the controller and POST the data, for further processing. Then, the main form will be submitted later on.

What I currently did,

main.html.erb contains the basic `form_tag`. Inside is a button which is `<%= link_to whatever_path, remote = true do %>`. in routes whatever is pointed to `contoller#whatever`

```
#main.html.erb

<%= form_tag something_launch_path, multipart: true, :novalidate => 'novalidate',  :method => 'post', :remote => true  do %>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
<%= link_to whatever_path, remote: true do %>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Cool Button</button>
<% end %>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" id="task-form" style="display:none;"></div>\
```

In routes, whatever is routed to `controller#whatever`, so now this should call the `whatever.js.erb` file?!

```
#whatever.js.erb
$('#task-form').html("<%= escape_javascript render ('form') %>");
$('#task-form').slideDown(350);
```

Now I have a _form.html.erb file, which contains the form.

```
#form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for whatever_path, remote: true do |f|   %>
<%= f.input  :username, as: :text  %>
<%= f.input  :password, as: :text  %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Problem:

when I press the button, the slidedown form appears, but when I click submit, it sends the main form too.
1. Is it possible to submit the form to a controller separately? That is what I am trying above here. 
2. Plus, the `whatever` gets printed on the submit button.

3. Is it possible to chuck `simple_form`, instead have a simple `form_tag` html?